# Modifying the LIBGDX Application frame in desktop

Tags: java, user-interface, window, libgdx

I'm currently using libgdx and I am looking for a way to modify the frame/window. I'm looking through google for maybe tutorials and examples but I'm not really sure what to search for. What would be the correct term to look and if anyone does have any examples/tutorials then I'd appreciate them posting them.

This is for desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the desktop Libgdx uses [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Getting_started) to access OpenGL and desktop APIs.  You should be able to use LWJGL APIs from your desktop backend if you need to.

You will have to be much more specific about what you want to "modify" about the "frame/window" if you want a more precise answer.